# CAGradientLayerHides my UILabel text

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uilabel, cagradientlayer

I am trying to add gradient background to my labels (which are connected from UserInterface) , but it hides label's text.

This is my code so far:

```
//MARK: Grdient label func
    func gradientBackground(label:UILabel){

        let four = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        let three = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        let two = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        let one = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1).CGColor

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.locations = [0.0,0.2,0.8,1.0]
        gradient.colors = [one,two,three,four]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
        gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, label.bounds.height)

        let backView = UIView()
        backView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, label.bounds.width, label.bounds.height)
        backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        backView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
        label.insertSubview(backView, atIndex:  0)

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        label.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    }
```

Then I use the function like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //MARK: Gradient background
        gradientBackground(firstLabel)
}
```

My question is, what is wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check if it is your label "firstLabel" visible
check if your func draw img under the text

Comment: my firstLabel is visible , but I don't know how to check if my func draws it under the text.